# Where are round(), rint() (and so on) C++ functions in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, c++11

These pages:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/round/

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/rint/

imply that these functions are part of C++11, and Visual Studio 2012 seems to support basically everything in C++11... so where the heck are the rounding functions (not to mention the other additional math functions)?!

I know all about rolling my own rounding function, but it just seems ridiculous at this point. Am I just missing something here and there's some special combination of `std::` and `tr1::` or another header file to get access to these?

Comment: Those were added in [Visual Studio 2013](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/07/19/c99-library-support-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you say, VS2012 supports "basically everything" from C++11, but that is not the same as "everything".

[These functions were added in VS2013](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/07/19/c99-library-support-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx) which, for the record, still doesn't support "everything".

Comment: Ugh... time to upgrade, I guess! Thanks!